# Python mini-game isn't working correctly

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from random import randint
b = randint(0, 100)
print b
a = raw_input("Try your luck, choose number (0-100): ")
if a.isdigit():
    if(a == b):
        print 'great!'
    else:
        print('wrong! that number was %s' % b)
else:
    print "string isn't number"
```

And the problem is:
$ python luck.py
62
Try your luck, choose number (0-100): 62
wrong! that number was 62

Answer (score 3):

You compare a string (result of `raw_input`) with a number (result of `randint`), try to test with

```
if a.isdigit():
    if(int(a) == b):
```

Answer (score 1):

`b` is an integer. `a` is a string. You need to convert it with `int(a)`.

Also, it may be more pythonic to [ask forgiveness rather than permission](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing):

```
try:
  if (int(a)==b):
     print 'great!'
  else:
     print('wrong! that number was %s' % b)
except ValueError:
  print "string isn't number"
```

Comment: Your example code wouldn't fix the issue. It still needs to be converted from a string to an int. Just add int(a) in there somewhere.